Localhost authorize page not found
I have a single monolith application running on ASP.NET Core using ABP.IO framework. Currently having a problem with authorization with swagger UI. It was working fine but suddenly not.
When i click on Authorize btn on swagger ui it should open up a second tab with UI for username password entering. But it does not & displays ERROR 404 page.

All migrations are applied & database is up to date. Database also has the required seed data inserted by DBMigrator. I have tried a different browser too.
Here's my appsettings.json
{
  "App": {
    "SelfUrl": "https://localhost:44355",
    "ClientUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
    "CorsOrigins": "https://*.OnlineSchool.com,http://localhost:4200",
    "RedirectAllowedUrls": "http://localhost:4200"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=OnlineSchool;User ID=postgres;Password=admin123;"
  },
  "AuthServer": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:44355",
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
    "SwaggerClientId": "OnlineSchool_Swagger",
    "SwaggerClientSecret": "1q2w3E*"
  },
  "StringEncryption": {
    "DefaultPassPhrase": "•••••••••••••••"
  }
}

I have tried going through logs in visual studio's output tab:
[18:02:10 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/swagger/index.html - null null
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+InferEndpointType.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateTransportSecurityRequirement.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromQueryString.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated.
[18:02:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/swagger/index.html - 200 null text/html;charset=utf-8 11.6367ms
[18:02:10 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/_vs/browserLink - null null
[18:02:10 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js - null null
[18:02:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js - 200 13786 application/javascript; charset=utf-8 1.2154ms
[18:02:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/_vs/browserLink - 200 null text/javascript; charset=UTF-8 16.6184ms
[18:02:10 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/swagger/v1/swagger.json - null null
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+InferEndpointType.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateTransportSecurityRequirement.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromQueryString.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:10 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated.
[18:02:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/swagger/v1/swagger.json - 200 null application/json;charset=utf-8 68.2174ms
[18:02:16 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OnlineSchool_Swagger&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44355%2Fswagger%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=OnlineSchool&state=V2VkIEp1biAwNSAyMDI0IDE4OjAyOjE2IEdNVCswNTAwIChQYWtpc3RhbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D - null null
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri.
[18:02:16 INF] The request URI matched a server endpoint: Authorization.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+InferEndpointType.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateTransportSecurityRequirement.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ExtractAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractGetOrPostRequest`1[[OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ExtractAuthorizationRequestContext, OpenIddict.Server, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[18:02:16 INF] The authorization request was successfully extracted: {
  "response_type": "code",
  "client_id": "OnlineSchool_Swagger",
  "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44355/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html",
  "scope": "OnlineSchool",
  "state": "V2VkIEp1biAwNSAyMDI0IDE4OjAyOjE2IEdNVCswNTAwIChQYWtpc3RhbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ=="
}.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ExtractAuthorizationRequest.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateRequestParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateRequestUriParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateClientIdParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateRedirectUriParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateResponseTypeParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateResponseModeParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateScopeParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateNonceParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidatePromptParameter.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateProofKeyForCodeExchangeParameters.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ValidateAuthenticationDemand.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ResolveValidatedTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ValidateClientId.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ValidateClientType.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ValidateIdentityToken.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+ResolveHostAuthenticationProperties.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateAuthentication.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateResponseType.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateClientRedirectUri.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateScopes.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateEndpointPermissions.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateGrantTypePermissions.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateResponseTypePermissions.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateScopePermissions.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateProofKeyForCodeExchangeRequirement.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateAuthorizedParty.
[18:02:16 INF] The authorization request was successfully validated.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+ValidateAuthorizationRequest.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+HandleAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+AttachPrincipal.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+HandleAuthorizationRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+EnablePassthroughMode`2[[OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+HandleAuthorizationRequestContext, OpenIddict.Server, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f],[OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlerFilters+RequireAuthorizationEndpointPassthroughEnabled, OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+HandleAuthorizationRequestContext was marked as skipped by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+EnablePassthroughMode`2[[OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+HandleAuthorizationRequestContext, OpenIddict.Server, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f],[OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlerFilters+RequireAuthorizationEndpointPassthroughEnabled, OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+HandleAuthorizationRequest.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was marked as skipped by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+Authentication+HandleAuthorizationRequest.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromQueryString.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[18:02:16 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated.
[18:02:16 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44355/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OnlineSchool_Swagger&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44355%2Fswagger%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=OnlineSchool&state=V2VkIEp1biAwNSAyMDI0IDE4OjAyOjE2IEdNVCswNTAwIChQYWtpc3RhbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D - 404 null null 21.3307ms
[18:02:16 INF] Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code. Request path: GET https://localhost:44355/connect/authorize, Response status code: 404



Hi @Shahzaib Hassan, how do you configure in Program.cs?

Try with http.
I don't exactly know if swagger is available for monolith applications, if it is, try swagger.
in Http.Api.Host, confirm the AuthServer has the correct port in Authority.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
